# MVC 4 Client Side Validation or Simple Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

I have to put `type="button"` instead of `Submit` My Validation does not works..Any sample/Link/Example..
Also how can we achieve ClientSideValidation in mvc..
Is it mandatory to use Jquery/Javascript????